Transactions for providing liquidity to Raydium pools consistently failing
I recently began to deposit tokens into liquidity pools on the Raydium decentralized exchange, which initially succeeded with minimal issues, but today I was not able to deposit any further liquidity. The pools in which I have attempted to deposit liquidity are SOl-USDC and SOL-USDT. For some reason, every attempt at depositing liquidity results in a transaction failure, with no clear reason why it would not work. Occasionally, the reason for the failure would be indicated as 'Program Error: "Price slippage check"' at instruction 5, but most of the time, the failure indicated would simply be 'Program Error: "Null"' at instruction 5 of the transaction. I'm unsure why this is occurring and I'm unsure what I could do to fix it. I have been considering writing code that interacts with the Raydium program, and I would not mind receiving a technical fix that could be done in code (although, I am still fairly new to interacting with the Solana blockchain). I have not been able to find any answers online, and I hope that someone may be able to explain what is happening and can explain any potential fixes.



After reaching support, it turns out the primary problem was due to a lack of SOL in my wallet. I was informed that I should have 0.1 SOL at all times in my wallet to ensure that most transactions succeed. I deposited 0.1 SOL in my wallet and consequently, the stubborn problem went away.
